# $\left|\int_0^1\frac d{dt}u(tx)\,dt\right|\le\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^N|x_i|\left|\frac{\partial u(tx)}{\partial x_i}\right|dt$ for $u\in C^1_c(\Bbb{R}^N)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-derivative

It’s my first question so excuse me if it is probably not very well written. Reading the proof of Morrey's inequality (Theorem 9.12 in "*Functional  Analysis,  Sobolev  Spaces  and  Partial  Differential  Equations*" by H. Brezis) I got stuck at the following inequality: $$|u(x)-u(0)|=\left|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dt}u(tx)\,dt \right|\leq \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|x_{i}|\left| \frac{\partial u (tx)}{\partial x_{i}}\right| dt$$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^{N} $ and $u \in C^{1}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$. I'm new to advanced math, so can someone give me some hints about it? I apologize if it’s something trivial. Thank a lot for your kindness!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let $x$ be fixed. if $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^N, \ g(t):=tx$, then $g'(t)=x$. Hence by the multivariate chain rule
   $$\frac d{dt} u(tx) = \frac d{dt} (u \circ g)(t) = (\nabla u)(g(t)) \cdot g'(t) = x\cdot\nabla u(tx) = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} (tx) $$
2. The integral satisfies a triangle inequality $|\int f|\le \int |f|$. Hence
   \begin{align} 
   |u(x) - u(0)| &\le \left| \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} u(tx) dt \right| \\ &\overset{step1.}
   =  \left| \int_0^1 x\cdot\nabla u(tx) \  dt \right| 
   \\&\le \int_0^1 |x\cdot \nabla u(tx)| dt  
   \\
   &= \int_0^1 \left| \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} (tx)\right|dt
   \\
   & \le \int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^N |x_i| \left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} (tx)\right| dt
   \end{align}
   which is the RHS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @NunzioDimola no problem; good luck with Brezis, its hard but rewarding!

Comment: Actually I'm studing Morrey's inequality from "Lecture notes on functional analysis" by A. Bressan, and I've got stuked at another inequality involving $\nabla u$, so I've tried to find explanations on the Brezis book, but I've immediatly stuked by the inequality whitch I've asked in the present question.  I will probably post another question about it.